# How to create an onclick listner for a listview declared inside oncreate method of an activity

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have an activity to populate a listview. I have created the listview inside the onCreate method of the activity. Now I want to implement an onclick listner for the list. How to achieve this?

This is my activity class with the listview:

```
public class PollStationActivity extends Activity {



    static String response_str=null;
    static String response_code=null;

    String ac_code;
    String ac_id;
    String ac_lat;
    String ac_lon;
    String ac_name;

    // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PSList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // no more this
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_poll_station);

         //sendPostRequest();

         //Log.i("I am here","1");

            final String status_code_from_prev= getIntent().getExtras().getString("status");

            //Log.i("ss",status_code_from_prev);

            ArrayList<PSItem> PSList = new ArrayList<PSItem>();


            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(PollStationActivity.this);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

             try {
              db.createDataBase();

              PSList = db.select(status_code_from_prev); 

              //Log.i("Count : ", " " + PSList.isEmpty());

             } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
               }

             db.close();


         String[] fromColumns = {"name"};
            int[] toViews = {R.id.list_label_name}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

            ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_list_listView);  
            List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Iterator<PSItem> i = PSList.iterator();

            while(i.hasNext())
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                PSItem objPSItem = i.next();

                map.put("name", objPSItem.PS_NAME);
                map.put("ps_Id", objPSItem.PS_ID);
                fillMaps.add(map);
            }





            // fill in the grid_item layout
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_layout, fromColumns, toViews);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Where should I put the listview onclick listner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the listener right after you've initialized, for instance:

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_list_listView); 
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //Handle the click
        }           
    });
```

Even though you have not set the adapter for the list yet, meaning there are no items displayed, it doesn't matter where you set it, as long as you have already initialized the listview via `findViewById`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ListView then you should use OnItemClickListener. I would add the listener after you assigned the adapter.

I prefer using the following solution for handling click events.

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        // Create adapter for the list view

        ListView lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.WordsListView);
        lw.setAdapter(adapter);
        lw.setOnItemClickListener(this);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

This handler will be called when an item is clicked and provide you with the position of the clicked item.